# Play all songs in a queue

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py, ytdl

This is the code that I have:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases= ["aq"])
async def add_queue(self, ctx, *, url):
  a = ctx.message.guild.id
  b = servers[a]
  global queue
  try: 
    b[len(b)] = url 
    user = ctx.message.author.mention
    await ctx.send(f'``{url}`` was added to the queue by {user}!')
  except:
    await ctx.send(f"Couldnt add {url} to the queue!")

@commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases= ["qp"], case_insensitive=True)
async def pq(self,ctx, number):
  a = ctx.message.guild.id
  b = servers[a]
  if int(number) in b:
    source = b[int(number)]
    self.cur_song_id = int(number)
    await ctx.send(f"**Now Playing:** {source}")
    await self.transformer(ctx, source)
    
async def transformer(self,ctx, url):
  player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
  if not ctx.message.author.voice:
    await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
    return
  elif ctx.voice_client and ctx.voice_client.is_connected():
    print('Already connected to voice')
    pass
  else:
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await ctx.send(f'Connected to ``{channel}``')
    await channel.connect()
  ctx.voice_client.play(player)
```

I can create a separate queue for each server and add songs to it by the command:

```
-aq song_name
```

example queue:

```
Your current queue is {0: 'abcdefu', 1: 'stereo hearts', 2: 'shivers'}
```

I can play the songs in the queue with the command:

```
-pq 0 or -pq 1 or -pq 2
```

But the problem is that the bot only plays the one song and stops after it finishes, and I want the bot to play the next song after the current song finishes and keep going until the last song in the queue is played.

Please help me out with this....

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: Is your code tabbed with... single spaces?

Comment: No, when i pasted it here, the formatting got messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to solve my problem, I implemented this code and it works.

I passed my queue which is a dictionary, to transformer function, and a number which is defaulted to 0 (for queue to play from the start).

And using `after` parameter in play function, I kept calling the function and kept iterating the number as long as it is less than the length of the queue.

It auto-plays the songs in the queue.

I know this code works but, if any improvements can be made, I'm open to suggestions.

```
async def transformer(self,ctx, number, que):
  player = await YTDLSource.from_url(que[number], loop=self.bot.loop,stream=True)
  await ctx.send(f"**Now Playing:** {que[number]}")
  ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.transformer(ctx,number+1 , que),self.bot.loop) if number < len(que) else ctx.voice_client.pause())
```

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your dictionary (`{0: 'abcdefu', 1: 'stereo hearts', 2: 'shivers'}`) really can just be a list since the keys are basically just the indices.

Secondly, I don't have any experience with audio in `discord.py` but it seems like your `pq` function doesn't actually go to the next song. It calls the `transformer` function once and thats it. It seems that really all you have to do is just loop through the queue and play each song. Here is some psuedocode that could be helpful:

```
@commands.command()
async def play_queue(self,ctx,number=0):
  for num in range(number,len(queue)):
    song = queue[num]
    # play the song
```

Defaulting `number=0` would allow for the the entire queue to play if no number was specified.

Comment: Hi, First off, sorry for replying so late, Laptop broke. Anyhow, I tried doing that before. The problem is that the loop wont wait for the first song to finish, it just increments the iterator while the first song is still playing, which gives an error that says, AUDIO IS ALREADY PLAYING.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. There is a parameter of the `play` function called `after`(https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play). It is intended for error handling but it seems that it is used commonly to either repeat a song or play another one. Also check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65330780/playing-a-queue-of-audio-tracks-in-discord-py). It shows a really simple way to use the `after` parameter that fits your situation

Comment: Yes, I actually figured it out later that night!. Thanks for putting in efforts to help! Really appreciate it.